# "GROUP BY" Alternative that is not Aggregate of the Records

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL currently:

```
SELECT `fundraiser_page__via__page_id`.`name` AS `NPO`,
       fundraiser_report.first_name AS FirstName, 
       fundraiser_report.last_name  AS LastName,
       EXTRACT(month FROM fundraiser_report.start_date) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM `fundraiser_report`
LEFT JOIN `fundraiser_page` `fundraiser_page__via__page_id` ON `fundraiser_report`.`page_id` = `fundraiser_page__via__page_id`.`page_id`
GROUP  BY fundraiser_report.first_name, 
          fundraiser_report.last_name,
          EXTRACT(month FROM fundraiser_report.start_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER  BY fundraiser_report.first_name ASC, 
          fundraiser_report.last_name ASC
```

I'm accomplishing my goal to group these records by First/Last name, and Month of Year. I currently read out the amount of times this `User`/`"Start Month"` occurs. Now I need to split these records up into individuals. Rather than printing out the number of times they occur, I would like that number of records to appear on the query.

I only want the query to display records that the `Group BY "Count" > 1`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you don't use `GROUP BY` you get all the results as individual rows.

Comment: @Barmar Apologies, I was not clear. I updated my question to better reflect what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the aggregate `COUNT()` with a window function:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (SELECT fp.`name` AS `NPO`,
             fr.first_name AS FirstName, 
             fr.last_name  AS LastName,
             EXTRACT(month FROM fr.start_date) AS month,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fr.first_name, fr.last_name) as cnt
      FROM `fundraiser_report` fr LEFT JOIN
           `fundraiser_page` fp
           ON fr.`page_id` = fp.`page_id`
     ) f
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY fr.first_name ASC, fr.last_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Join a query that returns the individual rows with the subquery that gets the counts.

```
SELECT `fundraiser_page__via__page_id`.`name` AS `NPO`,
       fr.first_name AS FirstName, 
       fr.last_name  AS LastName,
       EXTRACT(month FROM fr.start_date) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM `fundraiser_report` AS fr
INNER JOIN `fundraiser_page` `fundraiser_page__via__page_id` ON `fundraiser_report`.`page_id` = `fundraiser_page__via__page_id`.`page_id`
JOIN (
    SELECT fundraiser_report.first_name, 
           fundraiser_report.last_name,
           EXTRACT(month FROM fundraiser_report.start_date) AS month
    FROM `fundraiser_report`
    INNER JOIN `fundraiser_page` `fundraiser_page__via__page_id` ON `fundraiser_report`.`page_id` = `fundraiser_page__via__page_id`.`page_id`
    GROUP  BY fundraiser_report.first_name, 
              fundraiser_report.last_name,
              month
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS x
ON fr.first_name = x.first_name AND fr.last_name = x.last_name AND MONTH(fr.start_date) = x.month
```

Also, if you only want count > 1, you should use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`. They only differ when there's no matching rows in the second table, and that will only return one row, so they would be filtered out by the `count > 1` criteria.

Comment: Thanks for you help!